# javascript script is hidden in source view

Tags: javascript, html

Why don't the script tags and content appear inside a div tag for example.

I have the following code:

```
<div>
                    <!-- BEGIN: YTV Syndicate script -->
                    <!-- Edit Section-->
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        alert('hello!'); //check if scripts actually works
                        var YTVSYND = {}
                        YTVSYND.key = 'xxx';
                        YTVSYND.template = {}
                        YTVSYND.template.name = 'ytv'
                        YTVSYND.template.size = 'size300x250'
                        YTVSYND.soc = '<%= Model.Code %>';
                        YTVSYND.type = 'career';
                    </script>
                    <!-- END: EDIT -->
                    <!-- === DO NOT EDIT BELOW=== -->
                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        var ytvSyndUrl = (location.protocol == 'https:') ? 'https://' : 'http://';
                        ytvSyndUrl += 'syncdn.youniversitytv.com/synapi/embed/ytv-embed-api.js';
                        ytvSyndUrl = "/Scripts/ytv-embed-api.js"
                        var str = "<scr" + "ipt type='text/javascript' src='" + ytvSyndUrl + "'>";
                        str += "<";
                        str += "\/scr" + "ipt>";

                        var script = document.createElement('script');
                        script.type = 'text/javascript';
                        script.src = ytvSyndUrl;

                        $("#fgm").html(str)
                    </script>
                    <!-- EOF: YTV Syndicate script -->
                    </div>
```

It executes just but when I check the source it only shows the comments

```
    <!-- BEGIN: YTV Syndicate script -->
    <!-- Edit Section-->
    <!-- END: EDIT -->
    <!-- === DO NOT EDIT BELOW=== -->
    <!-- EOF: YTV Syndicate script -->
```

and no sign of the script tags and the actual script .

Note: this is inside a jquery modal, i have the same script inside a normal page and it shows up in the source view.

[1st](http://img521.imageshack.us/img521/8281/capture1nn.jpg)

[2nd](http://img221.imageshack.us/img221/2890/capture2qi.jpg)

Comment: What browser are you using? How do you view the source code?

Comment: Are you checking the document view (with Firebug or Chrome Dev tools) or the actual source usually shown by right-clicking on the page and selecting a "view source" option?

Comment: None of those things matter, because jQuery strips the `<script>` blocks.

Answer (score 3):

When you load some HTML content into the DOM dynamically with jQuery, it strips out the `<script>` tags completely. Under most circumstances it evaluates them (with "eval()" which is more-or-less what the browser would do), but they don't remain available in the DOM.

You can see the code in the jQuery source [starting around this point](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/manipulation.js#L732).

*edit* — note that I'm *assuming* that you're adding some HTML dynamically. If you were not doing that, then the `<script>` tags *would* be in the DOM, and you would be able to see them in Firebug, etc.

Comment: @mircea. can I ask why you need the scripts to be shown in the source? What difference does it make?

Comment: I was trying to figure out why it has that behaviour. My problem is that the script is executed but the last line "$("#fgm").html(str)" overwrites the entire document instead just the "fgm" div.

Answer (score 0):

View source is not your solution

view dom is you solution

use web developer of firebug